# Forbidden file import from GitLab to Upsource

Tags: gitlab, upsource, jetbrains-hub

I have an instance of Upsource (2018.2.1154) integrated with self-hosted GitLab and auth plugin enabled. Commits, comments, merge requests and branches synchronize properly, but file contents are somehow forbidden from being shown.

Displayed error is: `/git4/Test2.java: file was not imported, forbidden by project settings`. 
In error logs there is stacktrace caused by `com.jetbrains.upsource.backend.server.core.db.ContentMissingException` with the same message
[image: Error]

Upsource connects through my account's private ssh key to my own repository.

GitLab project has public visibility and *everyone with access* can see anything (Issues, Repository, MR, forks, wiki, snippets):

[image: Visibility settings]

I've clicked through subjectively all project settings in both services, but I couldn't find anything that would look like one restricting such import. Searches don't show anything about this error.

Comment: Unresolved; We ended up switching to built-in code review tool in gitlab